# C# Properties and this-keyword

Tags: c#, properties, this

When should I use the `this`-keyword for properties in code?

```
public class MyClass {
    public string MyString { get; private set; }
    public void MyMethod() {
        OtherClass.DoStuff(MyString); // Or this.MyString?
    }
}
```

I know that if the type **and** name of a property is the same you **have** to use `this.` to make it work.

```
public string Emailer Emailer { get { return _emailer; } }
```

What are the guidelines for using `this.` on **Properties** and even **Methods** in a class? I know it makes no difference in the compiled code. It's all about... hold your breath... best practices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do whatever you and your team find most readable. Some people like to be explicit; I only  specify `this` when I actually have to. It will make no difference to the compiled code.

Comment: The question is mostly asked to get some hints on how to justify why one is more readable than the other.

Comment: @Seb: It's really just personal preference - do you like very compact code where occasionally you might have to think a little more to understand whether you're using an instance variable or a local variable... or do you prefer longer, more explicit code?

Comment: Aaah, "explicit", that was a keyword that helps me out in my underlying question. Mention it in your answer and get the regular Skeet-check-mark :P

Comment: @Seb: Look at the second sentence: "Some people like to be **explicit**."

Answer (score 3):

If a parameter name and an instance member have the same name, you will need to use `this`.

Like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private string something;

    public void SomeMethod (string something)
    {
        this.something = something;
    }
}
```

But I'd advice you to choose names in that fashion that you'll never need to use `this`. Doing otherwise is just asking for trouble - sooner or later you'll forget `this` somewhere and will have a hard time debugging your code.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not to use `this` is mostly an issue of preference and hence there is no right or wrong answer.  It can become a bit of a religous war though with devs.  I often find it's best to come to an agreement on the team one way or the other and use StyleCop to enforce the decision afterwards.

Personally I prefer brevity and only use `this` when it's actually necessary. But I'd choose code base consistency over my personal preferences here because it's a fairly minor issue.

There are a few cases where it's explicitly needed.  Extension methods on this and in certain cases to disambiguate an identifier come to mind.  I find these are fairly rare though.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Extension methods.  Side note: this is mostly likely to be an issue when you've defined an extension method on an interface or base class and would like to use that from inside a class implementing that interface or base class, otherwise you're probably better off implementing it as a method on the derived class.