# Accessing through this within a class

Tags: c#, .net

Inside my .NET classes I access my properties and members through `this`. What is the difference if I access them without using `this`.

```
public class Test
{
    private string _test;

    public Test()
    {
        this.Test = "test";
        // vs. 
        Test = "test";

        // and
        this._test = "test";
        // vs. 
        _test = "test";
    }

    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: this improves readability, but there is no difference.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3564260/701062

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference for the compiler at all. Use whatever is more readable. I prefer using `this` to show that this is a field/property instead of a local variable.

Answer (score 2):

`This` is just referring to the class's variable.  It saves you from being tripped up when you try:

```
private string Test;

public Test(String Test)
{
    this.Test = Test;
    // vs. 
    Test = Test;

}
```

The first one will work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

this doent make any difference till you have parameter with same name liekt his

```
public class Test
{
 private string _test;

 public Test(string Test,string _test)
 {
    this.Test = "test";//this refers invoking object Test i.e class varaible
    // vs. 
    Test = "test";//this refer method passed Test param

    // and
    this._test = "test";//this refers invoking object Test i.e class varaible
    // vs. 
    _test = "test";//this refer method passed Test param
}

  public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

so in above case method parameter Test hide class Test prameter , to avoid this you need to use this to refer current object of class

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in your code, but sometimes `this` helps you to specify the scope.

```
public Test(string _test)
{
    this._test = "test"; // sets class field
    // vs. 
    _test = "test"; // sets ctor parameter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in terms of the end result.

One thing is that typing this will give you intellisense that lists only member available within that class.

Also, if the method is an extension method on the class, then you will need to use this to call it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, whether you use `this` or not. It's just about readability.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the msdn page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz(v=vs.80).aspx

In C# `this` is primarily used to increase readability when you have variables and parameters with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference for the compiler. Use which is more readable for you.

```
public class Test 
{ 

private string _test;

public Test(string Test)
{
    this.Test = "test";
    // vs. 
    Test = "test";

    // and
    this._test = "test";
    // vs. 
    _test = "test";
}

  public string Test { get; set; }
}
```